# Inserting JavaScript giving errors in GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-map-react

I have two json arrays with which I am trying to produce Markers on a Map.

I'm getting the error:

> Attempted import error: 'find' is not exported from './data/geoData.json' (imported as 'geoData').

while trying to find the zip in the geoData array within the JS for the position...

As noted, the `console.log()` returns the correct value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, Marker} from 'react-google-maps';
import styles from 'styled-components';
import * as zips from "./data/zips.json";
import * as geoData from "./data/geoData.json";

function googleMap () {
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={5.0}
      defaultCenter={{lat: 38.5, lng: -98.5556}}
    >
      { zips['zipCodes'].map(zip => {
        console.log(geoData.find(elm => elm.fields.zip === zip['Recipient_Postal_Code']).fields.latitude); // I get the number
        console.log(typeof geoData);
        console.log(typeof geoData[0].fields);
        console.log(typeof geoData[0].fields.latitude);
        <Marker
          key = {zip['Shipment_Tracking_Number']}
          position = {{
            lat: geoData.find(elm => elm.fields.zip === zip['Recipient_Postal_Code']).fields.latitude,
            lng: geoData.find(elm => elm.fields.zip === zip['Recipient_Postal_Code']).fields.longitude
          }} />
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
  )
}
```

Console output:

34.197737
object
object
number

Comment: could you please add your snippet to jsfiddle so easy we can help you

Comment: @PramodKharade I'm new to React so I'm not sure how to structure the snippet on jsfiddle!

Comment: Could you please console log the typeof geoData and share over here?

Comment: Could you please console both (zips ,geoData ) json file alias inside googleMap() function?

Comment: @Ashu I updated the original post

Comment: geoData is an object type, btw it's expecting a named export "find" from your json file, I would say you to try this out Object.keys(geoData) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys